# should I pass a JSON string with one-time binding to a component to reduce watchers

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

Question: is this a good practice even though it increases performace by reducing watchers

Using Angular 1.5.
Creating a table(with infinite scroll) where the **content of almost every cell is a component.**

There are over 500 watchers on the page at any given time and this is causing a rendering lag when scrolling down.

To reduce bindings, I would like to **always** pass data from parent to child component as a string (JSON string when I pass objects) with **one-time binding**

like so:

```
//In parent component (table component) controller:

this.name = "bob"
this.info = {city: "ABC", country: "AAA", zip: "100001", location "123 ABC"};
this.JSONStringifiedInfo = JSON.strigify(this.info);

// In parent view
<table>
<tr>
<table-cell-component-1 info={::$ctrl.JSONStringifiedInfo } name={::$ctrl.name}></table-cell-component-1>
</td>...


//and now in table-cell-component-1 controller

...
 bindings: {
    info: '@',
    name: '@'
},

this.parseInfo = JSON.parse(this.info);
this.name = ...

//and I then just use $ctrl.parseInfo in template...
```

Comment: `@` is called attribute binding. One-time binding is when a double-colon `::` prefixes an Angular expression.

Comment: One-time `::` binding combined with one-way `<` binding is more efficient because the watcher goes away once the data is stable. Attribute `@` binding adds a watcher that never goes away.

Comment: One-way `<` binding uses the [AngularJS $parse Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) to evaluate an Angular Expression. Making that binding one-time `::` is sufficient to reduce digest cycle overhead.

Comment: thanks. so, it's possible to do this: `<my-component info="::$ctrl.infoObject"></my-component>` where infoObject is an unstringified object?.

Comment: also, I don't understand why `@` even has a watcher because the value never changes after being set. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### One-time binding
>
> An expression that starts with `::` is considered a one-time expression. One-time expressions will stop recalculating once they are stable, which happens after the first digest if the expression result is a non-undefined value.
>
> [-- AngularJS Developer Guide - Expressions - One-Time Binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding).

Use **one-time** **one-way** bindings to reduce digest cycle overhead:

```
 <my-component info="::$ctrl.infoObject"></my-component>
```

JS

```
 app.component("myComponent", {
     bindings: {info: "<"},
     template: '<p>{{::$ctrl.info}}</p>',
 });
```